# Using Single house subaddress locator in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, geocoding

I am running into a problem with the single house subaddress locator in 10.4.

I have two different 'groups' of addresses with units/suites/etc.

The first 'group' has addresses with the same house number and street name/type, and different units:

```
1234 Smith Ave Unit A 

1234 Smith Ave Unit B
```

The second 'group' is like the first, but there is a base address record without a unit:

```
5678 Jones Rd

5678 Jones Rd Unit A

5678 Jones Rd Unit B
```

Each address has a distinct point feature.

My fields:

```
HouseNum, Name, Type, SubType, SubNum
```

I configure my locator with `SubType = SUBADDTYPE and SubNum = SUBADDRUNIT`. All of the other address components are mapped like normal.

Here's what happens:
Addresses from the first group locate perfectly to the point with the correct unit.

Addresses from the second group ALL locate to the base address point that doesn't have a unit.

So it seems like the locator stops looking for unit information (even if it's mapped) once it successfully locates the standard street address.

Any ideas on how to get it to look further, all the way into the unit fields?

I also have the 'additional field' mapped to a field that contains the full, unparsed address.

Comment: Try to see what your candidate score becomes if you change the subtype from "Unit" to "#". If I recall this was an issue with the out of the box locator style.

Answer (score 1):

I combined the Unit with the Civic and then used the US One Address Locator.  I haven't found a locator that uses the Unit column.  It isn't pretty but the addresses geo-code in the correct location.